# Combining Cloth simulation cache?

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation, cache

Is it possible to somehow combine different cached cloth simulations? My problem is, I make jump cuts between scenes and this causes the cloth to go crazy between transitions, so instead of baking the whole thing in one go, I reset the cloth position every cut, so I pre-baked different caches for each new scene.

The reason why I want a singular cache for the whole thing is because having several caches' means I can't render the whole scene at once, I have to switch renders when doing the next cache. If there is a way to render each cache at the same time, that solution would be welcome too!

[image: Caching]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*... basically you have to rename cached .bphys files.*

---

- First enable to **Disk Cache** checkbox, it gives you an access to saved cache on your disk in .blend directory.
- Than **Bake** caches
- Than for safety purpose I would recommend to duplicate whole cache folder.
- In blender create one more sim called like *MIX* or what ever and let bake cache for a whole animation. Doesn't matter what result is produced, just save the blend file.
- Inside original cache folder delete all files starts *MIX* and all previously baked caches let rename with *MIX* prefix (so the first frame looks like *MIX_0000001_00.bphys*)

---

I expect your baked sims continues one after the other like from frames 0-50, 51-100, 101-150

- First_0000001_00.bphys ... First_0000050_00.bphys
- Second_0000051_01.bphys ... Second_0000100_01.bphys

If they doesn't you would have to rename frame numbers to be sequential as well.

---

Note:

- I see you have baked already, but if you didn't save to disk before and cache is saved into .blend file - I don't know about a way to get them out from .blend and you will have to rebake it.
- in some situations can be option to export sims individually as Alembic (.abc) and import .abc back as individual objects and animate their visibility in timeline.

Comment: Works amazingly, thanks. Was afraid of the difference in #_00 and #_01 in the file names would cause problems so I rebaked them all one by one so they all ended with #_00, other than that, did exactly as you said and got results.

Comment: Great it worked for you ;) Find-replace _02.bphys to _00.bphys, should work as well. I don't know about your project enough, but you can also do a part of sim, dupli object, Apply Visual Transform and continue sim from that point. Then collect caches as described above.